In Power Query How to Group By with multiple keys
I have a column "Name", in which each value is repeated twice. And each value has its own share (input data). I need to calculate the average share among the first occurrence of values in the first column, and the average for the second occurrence, for each subgroup (the subgroups are distinguished by the first part of the name: like input car 1, car 1, car 2, car 2, bike 1, bike 1, bike 2, bike 2, etc (word + number). An example is shown in the figure. I already created an occurrence index.

To solve the task, I used "group by" and most of my columns disappeared in the new table. And when I try to merge the tables, I get strange results with many rows being repeated million times. How can I do it properly in Power Query?
I got some answers under this post, but I still don't understand how those codes work. I can have other similar questions and still no understanding how to solve them

When you do the group, add an 'all rows' column as the aggregation. That will keep all the data columns in each table.

When you Group By
Click on Advanced

Then add grouping. For your case it will look like this

